# Azure SQL Server (elastic pool) connect slow

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database

We ar running a webapplication in Azure Web Apps using a database per customer (multiple accounts per customer). When logging in we connect the user to the correct customer database. This database is also hosted in azure (an elastic pool). It is hosted in the same region (West Europe) as the Web App.

Once the connection is pooled, request times are fast, but the first time a user log's in, the connection still needs to be created an this takes (quiet) a long time.

The connectionstring is build up using a SqlConnectionStringBuilder.

```
var csb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
csb.DataSource = "tcp:******.database.windows.net,1433";
csb.InitialCatalog = "***-***-***";
csb.UserID = "**-**";
csb.Password = "**********";
csb.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;
csb.Encrypt = true;
csb.PersistSecurityInfo = false;
csb.TrustServerCertificate = false;
csb.ConnectTimeout = 30;

_connectionString = csb.ConnectionString;
// Data Source=tcp:******.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=***-***-***;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=**-***;Password=******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Or are there some settings in azure to speed up the connect process?

[image: First request time]

The above request shows the first request to the application of a customer. It therefor includes the EF Migration Seed resulting in the first 2 queries not actually going to the database itself and quite a lot of queries (not all shown here) to the database.

Comment: I can't tell how long the connections are taking, and whether the time is taken by connection or by EF Migration.  Can you clarify these points?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: I don't know if i understand you correctly. But the diagram (image) i believe the connection to the database is created in the white gap. The actual green (and one red) bar's on the right hand side are the first queries for seeding the database. The first two i think are for database existence. The image is a screenshot from Application Insights.

Comment: I'm 99% sure you are seeing the EF overhead in terms of modern building etc. In the systems where I use this pattern, I have a loop on application startup that calls the init method on each customer database to ensure the model is generated and and updates applied.

Comment: What is this overhead you are talking about. Is it the database an table creation? Because the database and tabels are already populated. I do use code first migrations and all migrations have been aplied. I believe the right part is the seeding (addorupdate command) of some values. Localy, all is fast and i don't have the gap in time. I do have the same gab when connecting to the azure database. So i believe it should not be the app sever, but the problem is with either connecting to or azure sql itself.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved my problem eventualy. Seems i was matching wrong queries within Applications Insights. I installed Stackify and this gives just the little bit more information I needed.

Seem's Entity Framework does some things with the 'master' database. As the user in the connectionstring did not have access to the 'master' database it throws an error. Well, handling that error take's up quite some time on the app-service used and therefor returning slow. It just doesn't fail.

What EF tries to do is determine if the database exist by querying the master database wich is faster then connecting to a non existing database. If it fails because it can not connect to the master database, EF just tries to connect to the database itself. If connection to the database works, it continues normal execution like the seed method.